# how to access CRx registers on a multi core processor

Tags: linux, cpu

I need to set the CR4.MCE bit for all the cores on my system (4). I'd like to write a linux kernel module for that, but I am not sure how to proceed: How do you sequentially access all of the CR4 registers? I have read the Intel manuals and they describe a way to initialize each core, but this is done in the bios.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MCE support already exists in the kernel; see `CONFIG_X86_MCE`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to run the code to modify `%cr4` on each CPU in turn.  You can either modify the SMP startup code to do this at boot; or if you want to do it at runtime, you'll need to broadcast an IPI (inter-processor interrupt) and arrange to have each processor catch the IPI and run your code.